# How to force shipping quote and order totals calculation on shopping cart page?

Tags: shopping-cart

I have a store where, after the customer logs in, predefined products are added to shopping cart and the customer is directed to the shopping cart page. The customer has shipping country defined and this is set to quote.

This is done in `customer_login` observer.

The problem is that when the customer enters to the cart, it shows default country in the Estimate Shipping selector. Only after page reload the Shipping estimator and totals calculation is run, using the correct shipping country set before.

How can I force the calculation so that correct amounts are shown when the customer lands on the page?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()
->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)
->collectTotals()
->save()
```

Comment: No effect.   (15chars min)

Comment: Answer edited. Try this

Comment: Not still. Maybe I should do this in some other observer, but which would it be?

Comment: I wonder... Why "try this or that" if both statements are exactly the same? Oh, a semicolon! Really?